# Put a logo next to author's name

Tags: graphics, titles, author, authblk

I wish to add a logo using `\includegraphics` in case a certain information is available.

I use the `article` class with the package `authblk` and put in the preamble:

```
\author[affiliation logo]{first lastName}
```

where `logo` should be an image. Ultimately, the logo will be wrapped in a `\href` command (but that part does not seem to create problem).

When I replace `logo` with

```
\includegraphics[width=0.4cm]{L-orcid}
```

I get the error message

```
! Use of \\author doesn't match its definition.
\new@ifnextchar ...served@d = #1\def \reserved@a      {
#2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
```

Here is a complete example showing the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{authblk}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\fontsize{9}{10.8}\selectfont}

\title{adf}
\author[a, \includegraphics[width=0.4cm]{L-orcid}]{denis cousineau}
\affil[a]{my place}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Some text...

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, you can't use an optional argument within an optional argument, unless it is group-isolated. For another thing, `\includegraphics` must be protected in this context.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{authblk}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\fontsize{9}{10.8}\selectfont}

\title{adf}
\author[{a, \protect\includegraphics[width=0.4cm]{example-image}}]{denis cousineau}
\affil[a]{my place}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Some text...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @segletes Thank you very much: I learned one major thing today: no optional arguments within optional arguments!

Comment: Uh?! @steven-b-segletes I just note that the left margin is now moved about 1 inch to the left?  Any idea what is going on? If you remove the "landscape" option, the text is out of the page...

Comment: @DenisCousineau I don't use `\authblk`, so I just assumed that was strange, but predictable behavior.  I'll give it some more thought, when I have a chance.

Comment: I can't explain why it worked, but the lag was based on the width of the logo, so I "scaled" it by adding ``\includegraphics[width=0.3cm,height=0.3cm,scale=0.0000125]{L-orcid}``